# Can os.listdir() method list remote directories in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to list the remote directories in windows using os.listdir() method in python.
When I try to run the below code it says- FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified. Below is the code-

```
newList = os.listdir('\\\\servername\\d$\\J2EE\\IE\\FOIS\\jboss-4.2.3.GA\\server\\all\\tmp')
```

Comment: The error would hint at this not being possible to do with `os.listdir`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Could you please suggest me some other methods to do the same?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add "r" attribute for folders that are in remote PC.

EX: `newList = os.listdir(r"\\servername\d$\J2EE\IE\FOIS\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\all\tmp\\")`

Comment: rstrings in python are just raw literal strings. It does not magically allows you to access remote files

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify http:\ or https:\ in front of the server name for it to attempt to resolve the server name as a remote one.

Comment: http:// prefix is used for accessing hypertext files. It seems like they are trying to access files which are not necessarily served via http.